# Follow mouse with animation in Framer motion react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I have a custom cursor component in my react app. And for the smooth transition inside viewport I'm using framer motion. 
The div under the mouse has some custom styling and it is following the cursor without any issues. But I want that div to animate all the time such as rotate + change border radius or even change bg color also. 
From framer motion docs I went through the `keyframes` section and after applying the same instruction it does animate but stops following the cursor. 
It just stays top left corner of the screen and do the animation. But I want it animate while following the cursor.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const CustomCursor = () => {
  const [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateMousePosition = (e) => {
      setMousePosition({
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY,
      });
    };

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", updateMousePosition);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", updateMousePosition);
    };
  }, []);

  const style = {
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    width: "400px",
    height: "400px",
    borderRadius: "50% 22% 40% 80%",
    filter: " blur(100px)",
    background: "rgb(255, 67, 75)",
    background: "linear-gradient(#43d9ad, #4d5bce)",
    opacity: 0.4,
    zIndex: 2,
  };

  const variants = {
    default: {
      x: mousePosition.x - 200,
      y: mousePosition.y - 200,
    },
  };

  const animate = {
    scale: [1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    rotate: [0, 0, 270, 270, 0],
    borderRadius: ["20%", "20%", "50%", "50%", "20%"],
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      className={`fixed top-0 left-0 sm:hidden`}
      style={style}
      variants={variants}
      //tried setting animate={animate} but didn't work
      animate="default"
      transition={{
        duration: 0.3,
        ease: "linear",
        repeat: 0,
        type: "spring",
        stiffness: 80,
      }}
    ></motion.div>
  );
};

export default CustomCursor;
```

So how do I achieve the animate + follow cursor action here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the goal is to have the animated element follow cursor and at the same time show a loop animation, it seems that the `animate` values could be added to `variants`, instead of defining another `animate` property.

Simple demo of below example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-llmbnm?file=src/App.jsx) (the `blur` is turned lower temporarily in the example for better visibility of motion).

```
const variants = {
  default: {
    x: mousePosition.x - 200,
    y: mousePosition.y - 200,
    scale: [1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    rotate: [0, 0, 270, 270, 0],
    borderRadius: ["20%", "20%", "50%", "50%", "20%"],
  },
};
```

The `transition` on `motion.div` could be used to [specify](https://www.framer.com/docs/transition/##value-specific-transitions) the desired properties for each animation. The `default` key in below example can be edited to control the loop animation of `scale`, `rotate` and `borderRadius`, in this use case.

```
<motion.div
  className={`fixed top-0 left-0`}
  style={style}
  variants={variants}
  animate="default"
  transition={{
    x: {
      duration: 0.3,
      ease: "linear",
      repeat: 0,
      type: "spring",
      stiffness: 80,
    },
    y: {
      duration: 0.3,
      ease: "linear",
      repeat: 0,
      type: "spring",
      stiffness: 80,
    },
    default: {
      duration: 2.5,
      repeat: Infinity,
    },
  }}
></motion.div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...it works..but the border radius seems to be always round in shape...how do I change it

Comment: @buzz For me it seems okay on both Chrome and Firefox, so not sure how to fix that. Perhaps try set even lower `blur`?